# mySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE comma seperated

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert a csv file into a mySQL table.

All the columns in the db table are text fields. The data i'm inserting looks like this:

```
Store,Sales
London,"500,000"
New York,"750,000"
```

The query I'm running looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/Users/someone/Documents/Web/app/build/tempDataFiles/commaFile.csv' 
INTO TABLE someDb.sometable_Test FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But the comma in the second column gets picked up as a field terminator: 
[image]

Any suggestions as to why that is happening?

Comment: Are you sure the lines are terminated by `\n`? If the file came from Windows, the lines might be terminated by `\r\n`.

Comment: Yep that worked. Problem now is that some of my inputs will just be `\n`. Any reasonable way to detect if the line endings are `\n` or `\r\n`?

Comment: You can try the shell command `file commaFile.csv`. I tested on my Mac with a file containing `\r\n` and it says: `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`. A non-Windows text file reports simply `ASCII text`.